# Cannot launch GraphDB on Windows10

Tags: graphdb

The installation of GraphDB was completed successfully on Windows 10 but i cannot launch the app. No error pops, instead it doesnt do anything nor running at localhost:7200. Any ideas what might go wrong?

Comment: You might consider using Event Viewer to see what is the error when your system trying to run GraphDB https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/Article/75433

Comment: It might not be OS related, since I have exactly the same issue on MacOS (on a MacbookPro M1) on a fresh installation done yesterday.

Comment: Can you check the error file in Users/<username>/AppRoamingGraphDB/logs/main-<date>.log?

Comment: In the AppData/Roaming folder there is no GraphDB folder (there is only a GaphDB Free folder in the AppData/Local)